# Laravel multiple column eloquent search query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4

i am very new in Laravel,currently working with Laravel4.I am trying to add a multiple column search functionality in my project.I can do single column eloquent search query,But honestly i have no idea how to do multiple column eloquent search query in laravel.I have **two drop down menu**

1.Locatiom
2.blood group.

i want to search an **user** having certain **blood group** against certain **location**.That is, user will select a **location** and **blood group** from those two drop down menu at a time and hit the search button.

In my database,i have two column, one contains the **location** and another contains the **blood group** of a certain user. Now,what should be the eloquent query for such a search?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Simply chain `where` for each field you need to search through:

```
// AND
$results = SomeModel::where('location', $location)->where('blood_group', $bloodGroup)->get();

// OR
$results = SomeModel::where('location', $location)->orWhere('blood_group', $bloodGroup)->get();
```

You can make it easier to work with thanks to the scopes:

```
// SomeModel class
public function scopeSearchLocation($query, $location)
{
  if ($location) $query->where('location', $location);
}

public function scopeSearchBloodGroup($query, $bloodGroup)
{
  if ($bloodGroup) $query->where('blood_group', $bloodGroup);
}

// then 
SomeModel::searchBloodGroup($bloodGroup)->searchLocation($location)->get();
```

Just a sensible example, adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way but I think there is an error somewhere as laravel would not allow you to access a non-static function so instead of using

```
SomeModel::searchBloodGroup($bloodGroup)->searchLocation($location)->get();
```

you could simply use

```
SomeModel::BloodGroup($bloodGroup)->Location($location)->get();
```

take note of the **searchBloodGroup** has been changed to **BloodGroup**, that's how you will use it for all others also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $errors = $connection->table('test_sessions_table')
->where('user_id', $user->id)
->where('status_question', 'false')->count('status_question');
```

in this method your code takes the following form
SQL code

```
select count(`status_question`) as aggregate from `test_sessions_table` where `user_id` = ? and `status_question` = ?
```

orWhere your code will look like this

```
$errors = $connection->table('test_sessions_table')
->where('user_id', $user->id)
->orWhere('status_question', 'false')->count('status_question');
```

SQL code

```
select count(`status_question`) as aggregate from `test_sessions_table` where `user_id` = ? or `status_question` = ?
```

Personally, I recommend using two ‘where’

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler method you can try

```
$datas2 = SomeModel::where('location' ,'LIKE', $request['location_id'] ?? '%' )
->where('bloodGroup' ,'LIKE', $request['bloodGroup_id'] ?? '%'  )->get();
```